# Is there a place where I can see monster health tables for Diablo 3?

Tags: diablo-iii

I'm looking for some site that shows some health tables for monsters in Diablo 3 for every act and every difficulty.

Comment: That's not really possible, as each monster has a "base" health, but it gets randomized from there.

Comment: I'm not looking for the exact value, it's obviously impossible to save all the milions of combinations for each monster. I can do the math from whatever base values each monster type has. For example, the value for zombie - inferno difficulty is enough to find the value for any kind of zombie in inferno dificulty as long as there are some reference charts with percentages for each zombie type.

Answer (score 2):

The monster data has been partially analyzed, and is available at [Diablo Lexicon](http://www.d3lexicon.com/data-monster).
However, it is not very nicely laid out, and a lot of the data for each monster type is still unknown. A "Hitpoints_Max" field has been identified though, and perhaps this could be the base values you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I remember that Brady Games' official guide had health tables (includes the range between min-max possible hit points) for most if not every single monster in all difficulties, but unfortunately it isn't online.